# Read multiple excel file with different sheets names in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

To read files from a directory, try the following:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
path=os.getcwd()
files=os.listdir(path)
files

['wind-diciembre.xls', 'stat_noviembre.xls', 'stat_marzo.xls', 'wind-noviembre.xls', 'wind-enero.xls', 'stat_octubre.xls', 'wind-septiembre.xls', 'stat_septiembre.xls', 'wind-febrero.xls', 'wind-marzo.xls', 'wind-julio.xls', 'wind-octubre.xls', 'stat_diciembre.xls', 'stat_julio.xls', 'wind-junio.xls', 'stat_abril.xls', 'stat_enero.xls', 'stat_junio.xls', 'stat_agosto.xls', 'stat_febrero.xls', 'wind-abril.xls', 'wind-agosto.xls']
```

where:

```
stat_enero

     Fecha  HR  PreciAcu  RadSolar     T  Presion  Tmax  HRmax  \
01/01/2011  37         0       162  18.5        0  31.2     86   
02/01/2011  70         0        58  12.0        0  14.6     95   
03/01/2011  62         0       188  15.3        0  24.9     86   
04/01/2011  69         0       181  17.0        0  29.2     97 
     .
     .
     .

          Presionmax  RadSolarmax  Tmin  HRmin  Presionmin  
    0            0          774  12.3      9           0  
    1            0          314   9.2     52           0  
    2            0          713   8.3     32           0  
    3            0          730   7.7     26           0
    .
    .
    .
```

and

```
 wind-enero

            Fecha  MagV  MagMax  Rachas  MagRes  DirRes DirWind
01/08/2011 00:00   4.3    14.1    17.9     1.0   281.3     ONO
02/08/2011 00:00   4.2    15.7    20.6     1.5    28.3     NNE
03/08/2011 00:00   4.6    23.3    25.6     2.9    49.2     ENE
04/08/2011 00:00   4.8    17.9    23.0     2.0    30.5     NNE
    .
    .
    .
```

The next step is to read, parse and add the files to a dataframe, Now I do the following:

```
for f in files:
    data=pd.ExcelFile(f)
    data1=data.sheet_names
    print data1
    [u'diciembre']
    [u'Hoja1']
    [u'Hoja1']
    [u'noviembre']
    [u'enero']
    [u'Hoja1']
    [u'septiembre']
    [u'Hoja1']
    [u'febrero']
    [u'marzo']
    [u'julio']
        .
        .
        .

for sheet in data1:
    data2=data.parse(sheet)
data2
                Fecha  MagV  MagMax  Rachas  MagRes  DirRes DirWind
01/08/2011 00:00   4.3    14.1    17.9     1.0   281.3     ONO
02/08/2011 00:00   4.2    15.7    20.6     1.5    28.3     NNE
03/08/2011 00:00   4.6    23.3    25.6     2.9    49.2     ENE
04/08/2011 00:00   4.8    17.9    23.0     2.0    30.5     NNE
05/08/2011 00:00   6.0    22.5    26.3     4.4    68.7     ENE
06/08/2011 00:00   4.9    23.8    23.0     3.3    57.3     ENE
07/08/2011 00:00   3.4    12.9    20.2     1.6   104.0     ESE
08/08/2011 00:00   4.0    20.5    22.4     2.6    79.1     ENE
09/08/2011 00:00   4.1    22.4    25.8     2.9    74.1     ENE
10/08/2011 00:00   4.6    18.4    24.0     2.3    52.1     ENE
11/08/2011 00:00   5.0    22.3    27.8     3.3    65.0     ENE
12/08/2011 00:00   5.4    24.9    25.6     4.1    78.7     ENE
13/08/2011 00:00   5.3    26.0    31.7     4.5    79.7     ENE
14/08/2011 00:00   5.9    31.7    29.2     4.5    59.5     ENE 
15/08/2011 00:00   6.3    23.0    25.1     4.6    70.8     ENE
16/08/2011 00:00   6.3    19.5    30.8     4.8    64.0     ENE
17/08/2011 00:00   5.2    21.2    25.3     3.9    57.5     ENE
18/08/2011 00:00   5.0    22.3    23.7     2.6    59.4     ENE
19/08/2011 00:00   4.4    21.6    27.5     2.4    57.0     ENE
```

The above output shows only part of the file,how I can parse all files and add them to a dataframe

Comment: In the last loop are you doing anything else with data2, or are you just reading it? Have you tried appending that to a list and `concat`enating the results?

Comment: If you're still having problems, please share what they are so we can help? If not, mark your problem as answered please.

Answer (score 12):

First off, it appears you have a few different datasets in these files. You may want them all in one dataframe, but for now, I am going to assume you want them separated. Ex (All of the wind*.xls files in one dataframe and all of the stat*.xls files in another.) You could parse the data using `read_excel` and then concatenate the results using the timestamp as the index as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd, datetime as dt
import glob, os

runDir = "Path to files"

if os.getcwd() != runDir:
    os.chdir(runDir)

files = glob.glob("wind*.xls")

df = pd.DataFrame()

for each in files:
    sheets = pd.ExcelFile(each).sheet_names

    for sheet in sheets:
        df = df.append(pd.read_excel(each, sheet, index_col='Fecha'))
```

You now have a time-indexed dataframe! If you really want to have all of the data in one dataframe (from all of the file types), you can just adjust the `glob` to include all of the files using something like `glob.glob('*.xls')`. I would warn from personal experience that it may be easier for you to read in each type of data separately and then merge them after you have done some error checking/munging etc.

Answer (score 2):

Below solution is just a minor tweak on @DavidHagan's answer above.

This one includes a column to identify the read File No like **F0, F1, etc.**
and sheet no of each file as **S0, S1, etc.**
So that we can know where the rows came from.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd, datetime as dt
import glob, os
import sys

runDir = r'c:\blah\blah'

if os.getcwd() != runDir:
    os.chdir(runDir)

files = glob.glob(r'*.*xls*')

df = pd.DataFrame()

#fno is 0, 1, 2, ... (for each file)
for fno, each in enumerate(files):

    sheets = pd.ExcelFile(each).sheet_names

    # sno iss 0, 1, 2, ... (for each sheet)
    for sno, sheet in enumerate(sheets):

        FileNo = 'F' + str(fno) #F0, F1, F2, etc.
        SheetNo = 'S' + str(sno) #S0, S1, S2, etc.

        # print FileNo, SheetNo, each, sheet #debug info

        #header = None if you don't want header or take this out.
        #dfxl is dataframe of each xl sheet

        dfxl = pd.read_excel(each, sheet, header=None)

        #add column of FileNo and SheetNo to the dataframe
        dfxl['FileNo'] = FileNo
        dfxl['SheetNo'] = SheetNo

        #now add the current xl sheet to main dataframe
        df = df.append(dfxl)
```

After doing above.. i.e. reading multiple XL Files and Sheets into a single dataframe (df)... you can do this.. to get a sample row from each File, Sheet combination.. and the sample wil be available in dataframe (dfs1).

```
#get unique FileNo and SheetNo in dft2
dft2 = df.loc[0,['FileNo', 'SheetNo']]

#empty dataframe to collect sample from each of the read file/sheets
dfs1 = pd.DataFrame()

#loop through each sheet and fileno names
for row in dft2.itertuples():   

    #get a sample from each file to view
    dfts = df[(df.FileNo == row[1]) & (df.SheetNo ==row[2])].sample(1)

    #append the 1 sample to dfs1. this will have a sample row
    # from each xl sheet and file
    dfs1 = dfs1.append(dfts, ignore_index = True) 

dfs1.to_clipboard()
```