# Merge multiple files with slight difference in sheet names

Tags: python

In Python, I have the code below that reads all files with sheet name `'EA'`:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_, sheet_name='EA')
```

The problem is that there are slight variations in some of the files, for example some sheets are named `EA 1`, `EA X`, etc.

Is there a way to write the code to basically say *'include sheet names that have `EA` in their name'*?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [read-multiple-excel-file-with-different-sheets-names-in-pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125596/read-multiple-excel-file-with-different-sheets-names-in-pandas)

Comment: I should have mentionned that some of the sheets shouldn't be included in the dataframe, so we don't want all sheets, only those containing 'EA'

Answer (score 1):

```
import xlrd
xls = xlrd.open_workbook(r'<path_to_your_excel_file>', on_demand=True)
sheets = xls.sheet_names()
```

And then, filter out the sheets you need. `on_demand=True` loads sheets when needed. This will be useful if it is a heavy excel with many sheets.

```
filtered_sheets = []
for sheet in sheets:
    if 'EA' in sheet:
        filtered_sheets.append(sheet)

# Now load each sheet in filtered_sheets using pd.read_excel()
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether `pd.ExcelFile` loads on need to basis. If so, that can also be used.